# Which Transact-SQL query is most efficient?

Tags: sql-server

I plan to pass exam "Querying Microsoft SQL Server 2012"

I have one question that I have problem to understand.

Question is:

> **Which Transact-SQL query should you use?** 
>   Your database contains a table named Purchases. Thetable includes a
>   DATETIME column named PurchaseTime that stores the date and time each
>   purchase is made. There is a non-clustered index on the PurchaseTime
>   column. The business team wants a report that displays the total
>   number of purchases madeon the current day. You need to write a query
>   that will return the correct results in the most efficient manner.
>   Which Transact-SQL query should you use?

Possible answers are: 
A.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Purchases
WHERE PurchaseTime = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
```

B.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Purchases
WHERE PurchaseTime = GETDATE()
```

C.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Purchases
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR, PurchaseTime, 112) = CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112)
```

D.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Purchases
WHERE PurchaseTime >= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
AND PurchaseTime < DATEADD(DAY, 1, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))
```

This is source: [Which Transact-SQL query should you use?](http://www.aiotestking.com/microsoft/which-transact-sql-query-should-you-use-9/) 
According to them the correct answer is '**D**'.
But I do not see why is this more efficient than '**A**' ?
In 'D' we call two functions (CONVERT and DATEADD).

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**D** will be most efficient as you are not converting the datetime column to any other data type, which means SQL Server can use any indexes defined on the `PurchaseTime` column.

It is also known as `Sargable expression`.

**C** will ignore any indexes defined on the  `PurchaseTime` column and will result in a Clustered scan if there is one or a table scan if it is a heap (a table without a clustered index).

And queries **A** and **B** will simply not return the correct results as they will ignore any records older than when this query is executed.

Comment: B ignores older results. A ignores newer results than those that occurred at exactly midnight.

Comment: Why would A and B ignore older/newer results ?

Comment: Because of PurchaseTime = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) and PurchaseTime = GETDATE().

Comment: @user2451446 - in both A and B, you're comparing two `datetime` values using `=`. Only where the date *and* time matches will that compare as true. (In A you convert one value to a `date` but it will be converted back into a `datetime` since that data type has a higher precedence)